# Browser Toolbar interferes with CSS header region

Tags: css, html, toolbar

I am in the process of designing a web page and I'm using the following CSS to create the page header with the main header image centered in a 1000px width page, and for a repeating edge image going across the top of the body and underneath the header to spread across the whole browser page width.

```
body {
    font-family:  Tahoma;
    background-color: #0184AE;
    background-image: url('/images/headeredge.jpg');
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-position: top;
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
}

.whole-page {
    width: 1000px;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: left;
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 0 0 15px 15px;
}

.header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 120px;
    color: white;
    background-image: url('/images/header.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    font-size: 10pt;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    padding-top: 10px;
    border: 1px black none;
    position: relative;
}
```

The CSS above works, except when a toolbar appears. I'm using Chrome with a SEO toolbar and it displaces the centered header image correctly, it pushes it down underneath the toolbar so I can see the whole image.

However, the repeated body image is not displaced at all and the toolbar covers the top so many pixels. This puts the whole thing out of whack.

I've tried a few options in the CSS, but so far nothing seems to work. I'm guessing here, but I think the toolbar draws itself using CSS that 'exists' under the body tag.

Can anyone suggest anything, I'd like either the whole header pushed down, or not. Just so it's consistent.

Comment: "Chrome with a SEO toolbar" is a little vague. There is probably more than one SEO Toolbar for Chrome out there. Which toolbar please? So we have some chance of replicating the problem.

Comment: It was the SEOQuake toolbar which fits inside the page and scrolls with it. However, I'm concerned that this might be a problem with other toolbars as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the Chrome developer tools (hit f12) you can inspect (click the magnifying glass icon on the bottom) the toolbar element. Doing this you can see that it is indeed inserted to the body of document. This will unfortunately result in the actual behavior you are seeing. In other words, this is not your fault but the fault of the toolbar developers.

One (ugly) work around is to throw an additional div around your content and apply the background to that.

E.G.

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <div id="notBody">
      <!--Rest of your headers, content, etc here -->
    </div>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
font-family:  Tahoma;
background-color: #0184AE;    
margin: 0;
position: relative; 
}


#notBody {   
background-image: url('/images/headeredge.jpg');
background-repeat: repeat-x;
background-position: top;

}
```

Comment: Thank you. That worked, despite being an ugly workaround. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

in your header class change to `position: absolute;` and use `top` to set how many pixels you want your header to be from the top of the page.

```
.header {
    position: absolute;

   /* all your other styles */

    top: 200px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately that didn't work. The header disappeared completely. I tried absolute with 0px and 200px, no difference.